# Rails: Get only some items when using association (in the has_many part)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I use association to map between my Store model and my Product model, using Store `has_many :products` and Product `belongs_to :store`. In this case, I can simply get store info and all products of the store using this simple code:

```
@store = Store.find_by_id params[:store_id]
```

But, I recently added a **status** field to products. This status is set by default to ON and when the user wants to destroy a product, this status is set to OFF instead of deleting the product on database.

But in this case, in the previous code, I get all products (whatever the product status is).

Question: How can I get store info AND ONLY products with :status => 'ON'?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use default scope for your model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope where(status: "on")
end
```

update:

You can skip default scope like that:

```
@store.products.unscoped
```

If you don't want to use default scope you can try this:

```
@store.products.where(status: "on")
```

Comment: Thanks four your help. But this will limit all product queries to 'ON' products. This is OK to display products list or product info, but not to get stats. eg.: % of active products/total products created, logs,...

Answer (score 1):

You can add `:conditions => {:status => 'ON'}` to `has_many`

```
has_many :products, :conditions => {:status => 'ON'}
```

But it will show only "active" products for `@store.products`

Another way is adding named scope to Product model

```
scope :active, where(:status => 'ON')
```

So you can get all products with `@store.products` and "active" products with `@store.products.active`

Comment: The use of `scope :active` looks interesting, definitely give a try. Thanks a lot dimuch.